# Cannot log in via phpseclib even though same credentials work via command line

Tags: php, composer-php, phpseclib

This works:

```
sftp user@192.168.1.1
```

But when I try it programmatically via php cli using phpseclib:

```
$this->sftp = new Net_SFTP('192.168.1.1')
$this->sftp->login('user');
```

It always returns false. I have tried different versions of Phpseclib and nothing has worked. I even run 'whoami' from within the php app and the user is me, so it should work the same as when I am doing it manually, no? This is driving me nuts. What am I missing here?

EDIT:

I also tried using `Crypt/RSA.php` and `$rsa = new Crypt_RSA()`, then `$rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents({my_key}))` and I put this into `$this->sftp->login()` as second param, but it also failed to log me in.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess: When you do `sftp user@192.168.1.1` you're doing private key authentication. It doesn't appear like it from the CLI call you're doing because the private key is either in your `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file or because it's in your `ssh-agent` install.

If that's the case then what you would need to do is to include `Crypt/RSA.php` and then do `$rsa = new Crypt_RSA(); $rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents(...));` and then pass the `$rsa` variable into `$this->sftp->login` as the second parameter.

Comment: I tried exactly what you described as well, but that failed too. I should've mentioned that in my description. I tried a bunch of things. I even tried both version 1 and 2 of phpseclib but I got the same results.

Comment: I added an edit to the description about this. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Can you get the SSH logs and post them? The way SSH auth works is...  you send some auth data and if the server rejects it it tells you what auth methods it supports. Since you can do multi factor auth and each response can in theory give you a different list of auth methods it can wind up getting complicated but, anyway, if you could post the logs, that'd be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I will look. Im on a mac so they should be in /var/log/system.log but even when I make a successful connection manually via cmd line I don't see any 'sshd' or 'ssh'. I will keep digging...

Comment: I also tried adding this line print_r($this->sftp->getSFTPErrors()); but it produces an empty array.

Comment: I found that this is the error I am getting by digging into the library: NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE. But not sure why.

Comment: What I meant by SSH logging was to do `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);` before you initialize the Net_SSH2 object and then do `echo $ssh->getLog();` after `$ssh->login()` fails. This will let me see the contents of NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE.

Comment: I think I know what it is, and it's embarrassing. I think I was grabbing pub key vs priv key... Will verify when I get a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, embarrassingly enough, I switched the pub with the priv key. The lib works fine. My bad...